# How to make arithmetics with elements of 2 different matrix with numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, opencv

I'm working with Computer Vision and I want to calculate the coordinates of the chromatic diagram of a picture, which uses the formula:

r = R / (R + G + B)

I'm working with numpy arrays and created a 2 dimensional array to store all the values of `r`.

I don't want to use matrix multiplication, because I want to multiply only the elements of the two matrices that are in the same position (i.e. `finalmatrix[1][1] = matrix[1][1] * othermatrix[1][1]`, `finalmatrix[1][1] = matrix[2][2] * othermatrix [2][2]...finalmatrix[n][n] = matrix[n][n] * othermatrix [n][n]`).

The code I tried:

```py
fruta2 = np.ones((720,1280), dtype= np.uint8)
frutar = np.ones((720, 1280), dtype= np.uint8)
for i in fruta2:
    for j in i:
        frutar[i][j] =  fruta2[i][j] * ((fruta[i][j][0])/(fruta[i][j][0] + fruta[i][j][1] + fruta[i][j][2]))
```

It returned the error:

```py
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1280,) (3,)
```

The variable `fruta` is a RGB image of a fruit.

I understand that it's not working because one array has 2 dimensions and the other has 3 dimensions. But I'm trying to access the elements and do the arithmitics with it. What can I do?

Comment: Is `fruta` a 3 dimensional array? If so, you can get the whole red channel by `fruta[:,:,0]`, the whole green channel by `fruta[:,:,1]` and the blue channel by `fruta[:,:,2]` and simply do the operation.

Comment: Yes, it is. It's an RGB Image, so it have 3 dimensions. I will test you suggestion, thank you very much.

Comment: `i` from your loop is a row of `fruta2`, not an index.  So `fruta2[i]` is wrong.  Similarly `j` is an element of that row, an element of the `fruta2` 2d array.

Comment: If you do generate the proper indices, e.g. `for i in range(fruta2.shape[0]):`, use `frutar[i,j]` style of indexing.  It's clearer than `[i][j]` and more idiomatic for numpy.